# NPE returned by a mocked function spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, unit-testing, junit

I'm new to testing and I'm trying to learn unit testing using JUnit and spring boot and that exception popped up.
As you can see I mocked the behavior of the function I needed in the TopicSevices but I still get this NPE, I also tried to add

```
MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
```

But it didn't work.

The controller code

```
package com.example.test.controller;

import java.util.List;

import javax.validation.Valid;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.example.test.Services.ExerciceServices;
import com.example.test.Services.TopicService;
import com.example.test.model.Difficulty;
import com.example.test.model.Exercice;
import com.example.test.model.Status;
import com.example.test.model.dto.ExerciceDTO;

@CrossOrigin("*")
@RestController
public class ExerciceController {

    private final ExerciceServices exerciceServices;
    private final TopicService topicServices;

    public ExerciceController(ExerciceServices exerciceServices, TopicService topicServices) {

        this.exerciceServices = exerciceServices;
        this.topicServices = topicServices;
    }

    @GetMapping("/exercices")
    public List<Exercice> allExercices() {
        return exerciceServices.getAllExecices();
    }

    @PostMapping("/exercices")
    public Exercice createExercice(@Valid @RequestBody ExerciceDTO dto) {

        Exercice exercice = createExcerciceFromDto(dto);

        return exerciceServices.CreateeExercice(exercice);
    }

    public Exercice createExcerciceFromDto(ExerciceDTO dto) {

        Exercice exercice = new Exercice();

        exercice.setDifficulty(dto.getDifficulty());
        exercice.setImg(dto.getImg());
        exercice.setStatus(dto.getStatus());
        exercice.setTitle(dto.getTitle());

        for (Long id : dto.getListToppicId()) {
            try {
                System.out.println(topicServices.getTopicById(id));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return exercice;
    }

    @GetMapping("/exercices/filter")
    public List<Exercice> getExeerciceByDifficulty(@RequestParam(required = false) Long id,
            @RequestParam Difficulty difficulty, @RequestParam Status status) {

        return exerciceServices.exercicesFilterTopic(id, difficulty, status);

    }

}
```

The test code

```
package com.example.test.controller;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Optional;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.mockito.junit.MockitoJUnitRunner;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockBean;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;

import com.example.test.Services.ExerciceServices;
import com.example.test.Services.TopicService;
import com.example.test.model.Difficulty;
import com.example.test.model.Exercice;
import com.example.test.model.Status;
import com.example.test.model.Topic;
import com.example.test.model.dto.ExerciceDTO;

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest

class ExerciceControllerTest {


    @MockBean
    private ExerciceServices exerciceServices;

    @MockBean
    private TopicService topicServices;

    @InjectMocks
    private ExerciceController exerciceController;

    ExerciceDTO dto = new ExerciceDTO();
    Exercice e = new Exercice();
    Topic t = new Topic();

    @BeforeEach
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        Mockito.when(exerciceServices.getAllExecices()).thenReturn(Arrays.asList(e));
    }

    @Test
    public void givenDTOCreateTheExercice() {
        dto.setDifficulty(Difficulty.EASY);
        dto.setImg("link");
        dto.setStatus(Status.FINISHED);
        dto.setTitle("title");
        dto.setListToppicId(new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(6L)));

        e.setDifficulty(Difficulty.EASY);
        e.setImg("link");
        e.setStatus(Status.FINISHED);
        e.setTitle("title");

        t.setId(6L);
        t.setTitle("romayssae");

        e.setTopics(new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(t)));
        Optional<Topic> topic = Optional.of(t);

        Mockito.when(topicServices.getTopicById(6L)).thenReturn(topic);

        System.out.println(topicServices.getTopicById(6L));

        assertEquals(e, exerciceController.createExcerciceFromDto(dto));
    }


}
```

The Exception

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.example.test.controller.ExerciceController.createExcerciceFromDto(ExerciceController.java:58)
    at com.example.test.controller.ExerciceControllerTest.givenDTOCreateTheExercice(ExcerciceControllerTest.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:675)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:125)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:132)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:124)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:74)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:105)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:104)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:62)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:43)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:35)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:104)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:98)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$6(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:202)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:198)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:135)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:69)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1540)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1540)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:229)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.lambda$execute$6(DefaultLauncher.java:197)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.withInterceptedStreams(DefaultLauncher.java:211)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:191)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit5.runner.JUnit5TestReference.run(JUnit5TestReference.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:541)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:763)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:463)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:209)
```

Comment: you need to follow this https://spring.io/guides/gs/testing-web/

Comment: Already did, but it didn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this and it worked for me, however, I did not understand why.

In short, I changed the `@Mock` instead of `@MockBean` as suggested by @arbuzov. Then I got this exception:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext

To solve this I added this two annotations `@SpringBootTest` and `@AutoConfigureMockMvc`. Then I tried to test another method using the MockMvc there again the mocked behavior was ignored somehow, so I changed back to `@MockBean` which worked.

I would be happy to receive any comments and explanations of how it works, if anyone has any.

```
package com.example.test.controller;

import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.is;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.get;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.jsonPath;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.status;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Optional;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.AutoConfigureMockMvc;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockBean;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;

import com.example.test.Services.ExerciceServices;
import com.example.test.Services.TopicService;
import com.example.test.model.Difficulty;
import com.example.test.model.Exercice;
import com.example.test.model.Status;
import com.example.test.model.Topic;
import com.example.test.model.dto.ExerciceDTO;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc

class ExerciceControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @MockBean
    private ExerciceServices exerciceServices;

    @Mock
    private TopicService topicServices;

    @InjectMocks
    private ExerciceController exerciceController;

    ExerciceDTO dto = new ExerciceDTO();
    Exercice e = new Exercice();
    Topic t = new Topic();

    @BeforeEach
    public void setUp() throws Exception {

    }

    @Test
    public void givenDTOCreateTheExercice() {

        assertEquals(e, exerciceController.createExcerciceFromDto(dto));
    }

    @Test
    public void eznekfnzre() throws Exception {
        dto.setDifficulty(Difficulty.EASY);
        dto.setImg("link");
        dto.setStatus(Status.FINISHED);
        dto.setTitle("title");
        dto.setListToppicId(new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(6L)));

        e.setDifficulty(Difficulty.EASY);
        e.setImg("link");
        e.setStatus(Status.FINISHED);
        e.setTitle("title");

        t.setId(6L);
        t.setTitle("romayssae");

        e.setTopics(new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(t)));
        Optional<Topic> topic = Optional.of(t);

        Mockito.when(topicServices.getTopicById(6L)).thenReturn(topic);
        Mockito.when(exerciceServices.getAllExecices()).thenReturn(Arrays.asList(e));
        mockMvc.perform(get("/exercices/").contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)).andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$[0].title", is(e.getTitle())));
    }

}
```

Comment: What do you want to do here? Your first test used Mockitos runner and appeared to test just your java logic (albeit with some very mixed up mocking annotations)

This test includes a spring context with a real mvc test (and Im not convinced your actually using your topicServices mock.. you may want to verify that. You might be using a 'real' topicServices bean that's getting picked up by spring when your test conext starts) (also your @InjectMocks annotation likely isnt doing anything here anymore without that mockitoRunner

Comment: I got cut off due to length restrictions in my last comment..  if you can elaborate on what you want tested and how you want it tested, we can help sort out the exceptions

Comment: What I want here is to test two functions the createExerciceFromDto and the  allExercices function they are both in the controller. First I tried the createExerciceFromDto cz it's only java logic it when I got the NPE then I used followed what arbuzov suggested and got the failed load exception, after that I added the two annotations I mentioned before and it worked, once I did that I tried to test the second function but it didn't work so I tried the @MockBean on the service I was using in that case and it worked again. But I'm confused how this whole thing work.

Comment: You mentioned that my annotations were mixed-up therefore I would like a suggestion on how I can make my code better and thank you for the help 

Comment: When you discover an answer, it is quite normal to find new questions that you want the answer to. While it is probably OK to add these into answers as a small aside, answers are not actually for posting new questions. It is better to ask a new question for those if you can.

Answer (score 1):

try to use @Mock instead of @MockBean. It should be ok

Comment: I tried it but it gave me this exception

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext